# trying to write process memory and getting user defined literal operator not found

Tags: c++, memory

Hello im new to coding and im trying to write processes memory in C++ using a Calculator as an example. I cant seem to find why this is giving me a error at the memory address.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

//Findwindow();
//GetWindowThreadProcessId();
//OpenProcess();

//WriteProcessMemory();

//CloseHandle();

using namespace std;

int main() {

int newValue = 189;

HWND hWnd = FindWindow(0, "Calculator");

if (hWnd == 0) {
    cerr << "Cannot find window." << endl;
}
else {
    DWORD pId;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pId);
    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pId);

    if (!hProc) {

        cerr << "Cannot Open Process" << endl;

    }
    else {

        int isSuccessful = WriteProcessMemory(hProc, (LPVOID)25D09ED227C, &newValue, (DWORD)sizeof(newValue), NULL);
    }


}
```

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this?

Comment: Want to learn memory hacking

Comment: `25D09ED227C` is not a 64-bit integer literal. For that, you would need `0x25D09ED227CL`

Comment: Thank you what do I need to change to make it work in the future if I get the same problem again.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're passing an integer that contains letters as a pointer:

```
WriteProcessMemory(hProc, (LPVOID)25D09ED227C, &newValue, (DWORD)sizeof(newValue), NULL);
```

25D09ED227C is an integer literal but you've included characters from a hexadecimal number.

Just put a 0x in front to tell the compiler it's in hex.

using 0x25D09ED227C will fix your problem

You can also remove the `(DWORD)` from the fourth argument also